# CSS image right align - extra line in Firefox 6.02

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a right aligned image, which works fine in IE9 and Chrome 14. In Firefox 6.02 I do get an extra line. Application is using jQuery UI. **How could I avoid this?** Is my CSS somehow wrong, or is Firefox 6 known to be different - as far as I remember it was the same as in Chrome with FF5.

[image: Extra line in FF602]
[image: OK in IE/Chrome]

```
<tr class="ui-widget-content sideBarTopAlign">
  <td>Data file:</td>
  <td colspan="3"><div id="inputDatafileInfo">not read</div>
     <button class="ui-button sideBarRightAlign">
     <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-link" title="Show data file"></span></button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

with:

```
/* align some elements explicitly right */
.sideBarRightAlign { float: right; margin-right: 1px; }

/* align some elements explicitly right */
.sideBarTopAlign { vertical-align: top; }
```

The styles from jQuery UI

```
button { font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 1em; }
.ui-button { cursor: pointer; display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0.1em; overflow: visible; padding: 0;
    position: relative; text-align: center; text-decoration: none !important;}
```

Another finding, it seems to be related to the colspan, if I move it in the last of 4 columns it displays as intended.

Comment: I'm surprised Mozilla still releases major.minor.micro versions of Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a `no-wrap` applied to a parent `div` section. I do not understand why this resulted  in the extra line break - and only in FF - but it was the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

**simple**

give the time span a width and display:inline-block

also for the 743 label

the problem is that the span it too long and doesnt give the img to be floated right and top

Comment: Thanks for the feedback: When I do .iconSpan { display: inline-table; width: 20px; } and apply it to <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-link iconSpan" it does not show any effect. I have changed the width to 10px, this applies, so it is not ignored, but still an extra line.